# UITabBarItem icon not colored correctly for iOS 13 when a bar tint color is specified in Interface Builder in Xcode 11, beta 2

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, interface-builder, uitabbaritem, xcode11

I have a problem with the color of my UITabBarItems when I run on iOS 13 simulators, using Xcode 11, beta 2.  I have made a sample project from scratch, and everything works correctly when I do not specify a bar tint color.  However, when I do specify a custom bar tint color via Interface Builder, I get this:

[image: Both selected an unselected item icons have highlight color]

All items icons in the tab bar have the selected color if I set the "Bar Tint" property in Interface Builder to anything but clear.  When it is set to clear, the icons are colored properly. The icons are also colored properly if I compile and run in an iOS 12 simulator.

This seems like a bug in Xcode 11, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Fixed in Beta 5 - right?

Comment: Yes, this issue was fixed with Xcode beta 5.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On the surface, this might seem like a bug, however you can mitigate it by defining an .unselectedItemTintColor on your UITabBar instance.

```
self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Comment: This works as a mitigation of the problem, we'll see if Apple fixes this!  The original problem was still there in Xcode 11, beta 4.

Comment: This works! Thanks. As of Xcode 13.1, we still have this issue.

Answer (score 45):

There is a new appearance API in iOS 13. To color tabbar item's icon and text correctly using Xcode 11.0 you can use it like this:

```
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()

        appearance.backgroundColor = .white
        appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
        appearance.shadowColor = .white

        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .black
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .blue

        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .red
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

        self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance

    }
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: When I am changing appearance in button click then it is not working

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: This is the first solution that's worked for me (except I used inlineLayoutAppearance), after searching 5 different similar questions

Comment: Thanks you @PhoenixB, your comment actually helped me to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 7):

Use the attribute field "Image Tint" in IB.

[image: Use the attribute field "Image Tint" in IB]

Answer (score 3):

For Objective C you can use in AppDelegate:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:0.65f]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.black
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.blue
        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.black
        tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    }
```

Comment: Not able to change appearance in button click

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Samuël's answer. Here is the UITabBar setting in my app, it is 2021 already but still rare helpful information in internet about how to set `UITabBar` for iOS 13 and above.

```
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            
//            appearance.backgroundColor = .white
            appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
            appearance.shadowColor = .white
            
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .gray
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
//            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .yellow
            
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = .systemPink
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemPink]
            
            // set padding between tabbar item title and image
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
            appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
            
            self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        } else {
            // set padding between tabbar item title and image
            UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
            UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
            UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemPink], for: .selected)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

This works for me in swift 4. Just put this in the `override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` method and this will update as the view is changing.

So it will look something like this

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
}
```

Even if this is a bug(I'm not sure) you can use this to change the color of the tab bar item by using any color of you choice