# How to make tabBar clear in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift

I use this code to make tabBar clear:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

But in iOS 13 my code doesn't work. I tried to use this code:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) { 
    let appearance = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    appearance!.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    appearance!.shadowImage = UIImage()
    appearance!.shadowColor = .clear
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance!
} else {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

But in this case my tabBar have white color, not clear.

Comment: Scroll down a bit for a discussion of the new appearance API in iOS 13: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839374/uitabbaritem-icon-not-colored-correctly-for-ios-13-when-a-bar-tint-color-is-spec

Comment: @Koen If I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/58088270 I have same result. White tabBar. I change `.white` in answer to `.clear`

Comment: Did you try without the `backgroundImage` ?

Comment: @Koen Yes. I tried different variants but it is doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. But maybe this will help: https://sarunw.com/posts/uinavigationbar-changes-in-ios13/. It is about API changes for `UINavgationBar`, but maybe there are some hints in there that can help you.

Comment: And watch this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/

Comment: @Koen this works - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58180167/12145020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For transparent tabBar use - `configureWithTransparentBackground()`

For default tabBar use - `configureWithDefaultBackground()`

code:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.copy()
    appearance!.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance!
} else {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
}
```