# How do I set the unselected item tint color in an iOS 13 UITabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, ios13

Say I have a `CustomTabBarController` that subclasses `UITabBarController` and I would like to make the unselected icons red. Previously I would:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

This behavior changed in iOS 13 with the appearance of  `UITabBarAppearance` and I haven't figured out how to replicate the effect.

Help? Thanks.

Comment: Show your attempt to use `UITabBarAppearance`. And don't forget that `UITabBarAppearance` extends `UIBarAppearance`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839374/uitabbaritem-icon-not-colored-correctly-for-ios-13-when-a-bar-tint-color-is-spec