# UITabBarController tint color problem on iOS 13

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios13, uitabbaritem, bartintcolor

When I select first item in tab bar, the selected tint colour doesn't change, but when I tap second time the same item, it works then. That only happen on the first tab bar item and it looks like tab bar is refreshing. Tapping every other item in tab bar works as expected and doesn't have that problem. This only happens on iOS 13. 
I tried using `UITabBarAppearance()`, but it's the same.

Comment: Did u checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839374/uitabbaritem-icon-not-colored-correctly-for-ios-13-when-a-bar-tint-color-is-spec

Comment: Yes, I did, It's not working. @AdarshGJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your code in DispatchQueue and then try ...

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
// your code to change colour 
        tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor]
    }
```