# ios13 - UITabBar tintColor for unSelectedItem not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, ios13, uitabbaritem

In Xcode 10 unselectedItemTintColor property working properly but after  Xcode 11 with ios 13 UITabbar unselectedItemTintColor property not working.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTabbar.unselectedItemTintColor = .red
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58088270/8374890 for iOS 13+

Comment: try this: self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITabBarItem icon not colored correctly for iOS 13 when a bar tint color is specified in Interface Builder in Xcode 11, beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839374/uitabbaritem-icon-not-colored-correctly-for-ios-13-when-a-bar-tint-color-is-spec)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**iOS 13 with Xcode 11**

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
     let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
     appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
     appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
     appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.black
     appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.red
     myTabbar.standardAppearance = appearance
}
```

Comment: Note: you need to use `inlineLayoutAppearance` instead of `stackedLayoutAppearance` if you are using inline layouts (like on an iPad).

Comment: And if you experience truncated titles with inlineLayoutAppearance, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69457332/1271867

Answer (score 9):

**In Case of : iOS 15 with Xcode 13**

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.black
    tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.red
    tabBarView.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    tabBarView.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're my hero! This is exactly what I was looking for the entire day! Thank you.

Comment: "I'm thrilled to hear that it's working well for you! " @Alexnnd