# I can't customize the TabView as I want it to be with SwiftUI/UIKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I absolutely can't customize the `TabView` as I want it to be. I can have the "unselected item" in red or the "background" in black + the "border" in yellow but not all of them at the same time.

Do you know why?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            // Views
        }
        .tint(Color.white) // Selected item color
        .onAppear { setAppearance() }
    }

    private func setAppearance() {
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red // Unselected item color
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black // Background color
        appearance.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow // Border color
    }
}
```

Using `UIKit` to customize a `SwiftUI` view is an absolute nightmare but there isn't any other choice because you don't have any control of the "border/divider" by using `toolbar` and `toolbarBackground`.

Comment: Please provide an image of your desire and what you achieved by now

Comment: I'VE FOUND IT!!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/71934923/18547664